# Powers of Orbifold Fundamental Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

I have reduced a problem to $\pi(Y)^n/G^n$ where Y is a manifold and G is a group acting on the manifold. Can I "factor out," the $n$? i.e. $(\pi(Y)/G)^n$. Note that $\pi(X)$ is the fundamental group of X.

I can't seem to find if $G^n/H^n = (G/H)^n$ in general. Intuitively, it seems right, but I'm not sure if there is some edge case I need to be looking out for. 
Thanks.

Comment: You calculate fundamental groups of manifolds and don't know why $G^n / H^n = (G/H)^n$ holds?

Comment: I feel like this should be a duplicate, but I can't find the question anywhere...

Comment: My Group Theory class moved a bit too quickly for me, but I needed this thing as a sub-step for something else.

Comment: This is a silly notational question, but what set is $G^n$?

Comment: The notation is indeed strange. When $Y$ is a manifold and $G$ is a group acting on $Y$, the meaning of $\pi(Y) / G$ is not at all clear to me. Certainly $G$ is not in any way a normal subgroup of $\pi(Y)$, so $\pi(Y)/G$ is not a quotient group. Nor is $G$ acting on $\pi(Y)$ in any well-defined way, so $\pi(Y)/G$ is not any kind of orbit object. So either some information is missing, or the question is flawed in some other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it definitely holds in general. Define $f : G^n \to (G/H)^n$ to be reduction mod $H$ on each factor. It's clearly surjective and its kernel is clearly $H^n$ (exercise: fill in the missing details if you're not convinced), so it follows that $G^n/H^n \to (G/H)^n$ induced by $f$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: As an aside, this argument extends effortlessly to other categories where the first isomorphism theorem holds.

Comment: Thank you. I feel dumb for asking this now. I was thinking geometrically, when I should have just done the simple algebra attack.

Comment: May I ask what set is $G^n$?  @Thoth19

Comment: @squirrel $G^n = \{ (g_1, \dots, g_n) \mid g_i \in G \}$ is the set of $n$-tuples of elements of $G$.

Comment: @Najibidrissi: Makes sense now. Thanks!